# grouping a csv file in d3

Tags: csv, d3.js

Say I have a csv file like this:

```
decade,year,cat1,cat2,cat3
1970,1971,2,3,6
1970,1972,3,8,4
1980,1981,5,8,7
1980,1982,9,2,4
1990,1991,7,9,5
1990,1992,9,5,6
```

I want to group the data by "decade", remove the "year column", and add the "cat" column. So the final array looks like this to use in a stacked bar chart:

```
decade,cat1,cat2,cat3
1970,5,11,10
1980,14,10,11
1990,16,14,11
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `d3.nest` and `d3.rollup`. We can nest by setting the decade as our key and then rolling/summing up the cat values based on the decade. The resulting key value pair will include the decade as the key and a values object with all 3 summed up cat values. Check snippet below:

```js
var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select('#data_csv').text());
var valuesByDecade;

data.forEach(function(d){
 //group and organize your data as needed here
  valuesByDecade = d3.nest()
  //set the decade as your key
  .key(function(d) {return d["decade"];}) 
  //rollup and sum your cat values by decade
  .rollup((function(d) {
    return {
        cat1: d3.sum(d, function(e) { return e["cat1"]; }),
        cat2: d3.sum(d, function(e) { return e["cat2"]; }),
        cat3: d3.sum(d, function(e) { return e["cat3"]; }),       
    };
  }))
  .entries(data);
});

console.log(valuesByDecade)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id='data_csv'>decade,year,cat1,cat2,cat3
1970,1971,2,3,6
1970,1972,3,8,4
1980,1981,5,8,7
1980,1982,9,2,4
1990,1991,7,9,5
1990,1992,9,5,6
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't seem to be doing wat I want. I want it to output tree lines with the data grouped by decade and the cat values added up and the year column stripped out. Like I have above

Comment: @ronmac so you want to group the data and export to a CSV file? why are you using d3 then?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't want to export it as .csv file. I want it to output  three object arrays to use in a stacked bar chart. Not sure if this is the correct syntax but like this:           

     Object
      decade: "1970"
      cat1: "5"
      cat2: "10"
      cat3: "11"
 
      Object
      decade: "1980"
      cat1: "14"
      cat2: "10"
      cat3: "11"

      Object
      decade: "1990"
      cat1: "16"
      cat2: "14"
      cat3: "11"

Comment: @ronmac That is exactly what my code does... run the script above and look at the result. It returns 3 object arrays with what you need.